# How to store and retrieve neo4j index

Tags: java, database, graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I am working on a neo4j-related project and I don't quite understand the "index" in neo4j. In a relational database, we have tables and indexes on persistent disk.

I am assuming it is the same for neo4j, the nodes, relationships (edges) and indexes are persistent. I might be wrong about this.

In this example, https://github.com/mrhooray/neo4j-sample/blob/master/src/EmbeddedNeo4jWithIndexing.java

```
public class EmbeddedNeo4jWithIndexing {
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/home/mrhooray/Documents/neo4j_db/";
    private static final String USERNAME_KEY = "username";
    private static GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    private static Index<Node> nodeIndex; 
    //...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           //...
           // index is created as following
           nodeIndex = graphDb.index().forNodes("nodes");
    }

    // and used to insert data
    private static Node createAndIndexUser(final String username) {
        Node node = graphDb.createNode();
        node.setProperty(USERNAME_KEY, username);
        nodeIndex.add(node, USERNAME_KEY, username);
        return node;
    }
}
```

EmbeddedNeo4jWithIndexing is an abstraction of a graph database. However, what if I created and populated a graph database and then shutdown the program. Then later I would like to access the same database with the same index again, do I just create another object of EmbeddedNeo4jWithIndexing? How can I get the original index back?

call

```
nodeIndex = graphDb.index().forNodes("nodes");
```

again? It doesn't seem to work that way.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks correct. The `index().forNodes("nodes");` is basically a create or get operation, which will create the index if it doesn't exist, otherwise it'll return the index object that is for that index name.

In your code, make sure you are using transactions, as you won't actually persist any information if you don't. Otherwise, to perform a lookup the next time you need to, you just do `nodeIndex.get(USERNAME_KEY, username)` and it will return you any nodes mapped to that in the index.